# How to filter datagridview using treeview checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, treeview

I've a `datagridview` which gets its data from a database and `treeview checkBoxes` which should be used as a filter.

I want to filter the `datagridview` by checking / unchecking one or more of the `treeview checkedboxes` and should display me the selected item in the `datagridview` with it relating Amounts:

[image]
[image]

My code I' trying to convert from `checkedboxes` into `treeview checkboxes`:

```
private void treeview1()
{

    string rowFilter = string.Empty;

    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
  // root nodes to filter on,to check children nodes under each root node
        if (node.Text == "AreaCode")
        {
  // Iterate through the root node's children nodes and build filter based      on them being checked or unchecked
            foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
            {
                if (childNode.Checked)
                {
                    if (rowFilter.Length > 0)
                    {
                        rowFilter += " OR ";
                    }
                    rowFilter += "[AreaCode] = " + childNode.Text;
                    MessageBox.Show(rowFilter);
                }
            }
        }
 }




    // Apply rowFilter to DataView.RowFilter 

    try{
        //Check an see what's in the dgv
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = rowFilter;
        datagridview1.DataSource = dv;
        }
    catch(Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("IT IS NOT WORKING");
        }


}


 private void treeview2()
{

    string rowFilter = string.Empty;

    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        // In case you add more root nodes to filter on, you'll want to check children nodes under each root node
        if (node.Text == "Grant")
        {
            // Iterate through the root node's children nodes and build your filter based on them being checked or unchecked
            foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
            {
                if (childNode.Checked)
                {
                    if (rowFilter.Length > 0)
                    {
                        rowFilter += " OR ";
                    }

     // Outcome is a string NOT WORKING RIGHT                   
  rowFilter += "[Grant] = " + childNode.Text; // gets the selected string but   can filter If I put = 'Yes' ist makes it static. I need to make it dynamic
                    MessageBox.Show(rowFilter);
                }
            }
        }
  }




    // Apply rowFilter to DataView.RowFilter 

    try{
        //Check an see what's in the dgv
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = rowFilter;
        datagridview1.DataSource = dv;
        }
    catch(Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("IT IS NOT WORKING");
        }


}

 private void treeview3()
{

    string rowFilter = string.Empty;

    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        // In case you add more root nodes to filter on, you'll want to check children nodes under each root node
        if (node.Text == "Land")
        {
            // Iterate through the root node's children nodes and build your filter based on them being checked or unchecked
            foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
            {
                if (childNode.Checked)
                {
                    if (rowFilter.Length > 0)
                    {
                        rowFilter += " OR ";
                    }

    // Outcome is a string NOT WORKING RIGHT                   
    rowFilter += "[Land] = " + childNode.Text; // gets the selected string but can filter If I put = 'Mitte' ist makes it static. I need to make it dynamic
                    MessageBox.Show(rowFilter);
                }
            }
        }
    }




    // Apply rowFilter to DataView.RowFilter 

    try{
        //Check an see what's in the dgv
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.RowFilter = rowFilter;
        datagridview1.DataSource = dv;
        }
    catch(Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("IT IS NOT WORKING");
        }


}




  private void treeViewAfterCheck_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        // Any node that is checked/unchecked will have all of its 
        // children nodes checked/unchecked
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode childNode in e.Node.Nodes)
            {
                childNode.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
            }
        }

   treeview1();
   treeview2();
    treeview3();

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reconstructing my entire answer based on what I'm understanding what you're wanting to do.

The first thing you have to understand is design.  Since you have three treeviews now, how do you want them to work together when you apply the filter?  Do you want them as an AND condition or an OR condition?

Example AND condition, ([AreaCode] = 11 OR [AreaCode] == 16]) AND ([Land] = 'North' OR [Land] = 'East')

Example OR condition, ([AreaCode] = 11 OR [AreaCode] == 16]) OR ([Land] = 'North' OR [Land] = 'East')

If you don't understand the difference, I suggest studying up on some SQL.

Now for you to accomplish a single filter to apply to your DataGridView you have to go through all treeviews in one method and build your rowFilter string appropriatley.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// All treeviews fire this event when a node's checkbox is check/unchecked
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void treeView_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        // Any node that is checked/unchecked will have all of its 
        // children nodes checked/unchecked
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode childNode in e.Node.Nodes)
            {
                childNode.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
            }
        }

        // Now it doesn't matter which treeview we are working with, let's build the rowFilter
        // with all three treeviews
        string areaCodeRowFilter = string.Empty;

        // The order in which we use the treeviews is not important
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
        {
            // treeView1 in this case is AreaCode
            // The foreach is going through all root nodes and we have to 
            //  traverse into the children nodes
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                // Iterate through the children nodes to start building the rowFilter string
                foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
                {
                    if (childNode.Checked)
                    {
                        if (areaCodeRowFilter.Length > 0)
                        {
                            areaCodeRowFilter += " OR ";
                        }
                        areaCodeRowFilter += "[AreaCode] = " + childNode.Text;
                    }
                }
            }
        } // End foreach using treeView1 (AreaCode)

        // Do the same thing with the other treeViews
        // The order in which we use the treeviews is not important
        string landRowFilter = string.Empty;
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeView2.Nodes)
        {
            // Since these values are strings,
            // they have to be wrapped in single quotes.

            // Example, [Land] = 'North' OR [Land] = 'West'

            // treeView2 in this case is Land
            // The foreach is going through all root nodes and we have to 
            // traverse into the children nodes
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                // Iterate through the children nodes to start building the rowFilter string
                foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
                {
                    if (childNode.Checked)
                    {
                        if (landRowFilter.Length > 0)
                        {
                            landRowFilter += " OR ";
                        }
                        landRowFilter += "[Land] = '" + childNode.Text + "'";
                    }
                }
            }
        } // End foreach using treeView2 (Land)

        string grantRowFilter = string.Empty;
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeView3.Nodes)
        {
            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
                {
                    if (childNode.Checked)
                    {
                        if (grantRowFilter.Length > 0)
                        {
                            grantRowFilter += " OR ";
                        }
                        grantRowFilter += "[Grant] = '" + childNode.Text + "'";
                    }
                }
            }
        } // End foreach using treeView3 (Grant)

        // We have three rowFilter strings that we have to concantenate and set into the DataView.RowFilter
        // How will you use these filters as an AND or an OR?
        // I will use them as an AND.  I will also wrap each part 
        // of the rowFilter string in parenthesis.  

        string rowFilter = string.Empty;
        if (areaCodeRowFilter.Length > 0)
        {
            areaCodeRowFilter = "(" + areaCodeRowFilter + ")";
            rowFilter = areaCodeRowFilter;
        }
        if (landRowFilter.Length > 0)
        {
            landRowFilter = "(" + landRowFilter + ")";
            if (rowFilter.Length > 0)
            {
                rowFilter += " AND " + landRowFilter;
            }
            else
            {
                rowFilter = landRowFilter;
            }
        }
        if (grantRowFilter.Length > 0)
        {
            grantRowFilter = "(" + grantRowFilter + ")";
            if (rowFilter.Length > 0)
            {
                rowFilter += " AND " + grantRowFilter;
            }
            else
            {
                rowFilter = grantRowFilter;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(rowFilter);

        // Take out the MessageBox.Show, I've only got it here to show you 
        // how the string looks when it's built

        // Apply rowFilter to your DataView.RowFilter
    }
```

Results from MessageBox:

[image]

The one thing that I don't like about this approach, is if you click a root node, all the children nodes will be check/unchecked and this method will fire for each event.  But this should get the job done.  If this satisfies what you're wanting, I'd also suggest trying to figure out how to shorten this event up.  What I've given you is just the basic approach, and in my opinion, the code is a little sloppy an can be written cleaner.  If you try to shorten this, be sure to have a copy of this original in case you need to fall back to the working solution.

I've enjoyed helping you.  To become better, you're going to have to play around with the code do lots of debugging, but always make sure you understand what you want to do and how you expect your program to work before you start writing the code.

Comment: I am having problems with the filtering. Instead of using int (11,16 and 31) for the `treeview checkboxes` **child node**, I'm now using strings (Yes, No) and the dv.RowFilter istn't getting the results no moe. As i debug : **The column name Yes can't be found if I debug.**

Comment: You'll have to post code for me to review, but your column names according to your current code are: AreaCode, Amount1, Amount2, and Amount3.  As far as I know, you don't have a column name called Yes.  When you apply a filter to RowFilter, it's just like making a where clause in a SQL statement [columnName] [operator (<, >, <=, >=, =, etc..)] [columnValue].  For your reference, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have edited my question and posted new images. I now have three difgferent `treeview checkboxes`. so if i select AreaCode = **16** and Grant = **Yes** and Land = **West** (or more choices) its should filter and display me that. But I am having problem with the logic and the connectivity. Would be glad for help once again.

Comment: @Shar1er80.I think my logic thinking has drop down :). The rowFilter is unfortunately working for only `treeview1` which is **AreaCode**.  What abt the other two `treeview2` which is for **Grant** and `treeview3` which is for **Land**?  And why the `else if` statement when there is no second **root node** within `treeview1`?
I think the problem for it not working for the other ones (`treeview1 &2`) is that they are called within the `treeview1` method. Am I right with my thoughts?

Comment: You are correct, so your logic thinking has not dropped ;-) I didn't realize that the method we used to set the RowFilter was just for treeView1, but a generic method that would analyze all trees and build your rowFilter string.  Having said that, the else if needs to be pulled out into its own for each and look just like with the first treeview

Comment: @ Shar1er80. hahaha. I thought I' m going crazy with my thinking. Ok I will be editing my code once again in 2 min. Can u please take a look? I 'm having two problems now. At the `treeview2` which is for **Grant** and `treeview3` which is for **Land** returns a `string` so it doesn't accept the childNode.text.[Column Yes couldn't not be found] Secondly I' m trying to call all treeviews method in a general `AfterCheck even`t but itsn't working. Lastly how to do the concatenation so that I filter through  regardless of which `checkedBox` I select (dynamically). I hope u understand me :)

Comment: @Shar1er80.Just came back home. Thanks for the useful advice. Ireally appreciate it. I will be studying ur edited code tomorrow and will implement  it and will also try to advance it. Thanks again for ur warming patience.